# Add value to column and previous row if condition is met

Tags: r

Imagine I have a dataframe df with those columns

```
RT   Error Number
0.2  0     4
0.3  0     4
0.3  1     3
0.4  0     4
0.2  1     3
0.2  0     4      
0.3  0     3
```

What I did is add a column which I do with

```
Df["ThirdColumn"] <- 0
```

Df:

```
RT   Error Number ThirdColumn
0.2  0     4      0
0.3  0     4      0
0.3  1     3      0
0.4  0     4      0
0.2  1     3      0  
0.2  0     4      0
0.3  0     3      0
```

Now I would like to modify the 0's in ThirdColumn that precede an Error ==1 & Number == 3 with 8
and the 0's in ThirdColumn that precede an Error ==0 with Number == 3 with 9

Expected result

```
RT   Error Number ThirdColumn
0.2  0     4      0
0.3  0     4      8
0.3  1     3      0
0.4  0     4      8
0.2  1     3      0  
0.2  0     4      9
0.3  0     3      0
```

I tried several if statements but I keep getting errors.

Answer (score 1):

Which rows satisfy the criteria?

```
> W = which((Df$Error==1 | Df$Error==0) & Df$Number==3)
```

Now set the value in rows `W-1` and use `9-Df$Error` to get 9 when `Error` is 0 and 8 when `Error` is 1:

```
> Df$ThirdColumn[W-1] = 9-Df$Error[W]
> 
> Df
   RT Error Number ThirdColumn
1 0.2     0      4           0
2 0.3     0      4           8
3 0.3     1      3           0
4 0.4     0      4           8
5 0.2     1      3           0
6 0.2     0      4           9
7 0.3     0      3           0
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with `which`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Df)[which(Error==1 & Number==3)-1, ThirdColumn := 8]
Df[which(Error==0 & Number==3)-1, ThirdColumn := 9]
Df
#    RT Error Number ThirdColumn
#1: 0.2     0      4           0
#2: 0.3     0      4           8
#3: 0.3     1      3           0
#4: 0.4     0      4           8
#5: 0.2     1      3           0
#6: 0.2     0      4           9
#7: 0.3     0      3           0
```

---

We can also do this with `base R`

```
i1 <- with(Df, which(Error ==1 & Number == 3)-1)
i2 <- with(Df, which(Error ==0 & Number == 3)-1)
Df$ThirdColumn[i1] <- 8
Df$ThirdColumn[i2] <- 9
```

Comment: Thank you akrun I will try it out and come back to upvote this if it works. Have a good one.

Comment: It works thank you, I upvoted your answer, although stack does not take into account since my account is fresh, IMO this answer was the easiest to understand among the others.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `lead` from `dplyr` to get leading values of columns.

```
library(dplyr)
Df$ThirdColumn <- with(Df, ifelse(lead(Error) == 1 & lead(Number == 3), 8, 
                           ifelse(lead(Error) == 0 & lead(Number) == 3, 9, 0)))
```

The last number would return `NA` in this case which can be later changed to 0 easily.

```
Df$ThirdColumn[nrow(Df)] <- 0

Df
#   RT Error Number ThirdColumn
#1 0.2     0      4           0
#2 0.3     0      4           8
#3 0.3     1      3           0
#4 0.4     0      4           8
#5 0.2     1      3           0
#6 0.2     0      4           9
#7 0.3     0      3           0
```